# NSUserDefaults resets to wrong 'Webkit' content on iOS simulator 17

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, nsuserdefaults

I'm using the [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] to store some values. It worked on previous simulators and still works on real devices.

However, after upgrading to iOS 17 simulators, the NSUserDefaults stopped working. When inspecting the content, it looks like the standardUserDefaults are beeing reset to the same content each time i launch the app.

Inspecting the full content of the standard userdefaults:

```
SDictionary *dic = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
```

Always has the same content on app startup, 580 key/values:

[image: NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults content]

Any idea where these values are coming from and how to avoid this behaviour?